# SVG resized instead of overflow

Tags: html, css, image, svg

Consider the following SVG image in an HTML page:

```
<img src="https://keyller.io/generators/fr/solfege/cle-de-sol/img/treble-clef-9-sol.svg">
```

The following CSS is applied to the image:

```
img { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;    
}
```

When the image get closer to the right limit of the viewport, the image is resized to fit entirely in the page.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/hr6mowxp/1/

If I replace the image with a jpg, the image now overflows and is not resized.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/hr6mowxp/2/

Therefore the following SVG overflows:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Stack_Overfl
ow_logo.svg">
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/hr6mowxp/3/

Can someone explain me why the first SVG is resized while the other images overflows?

How to perform overflow on the first image instead of resizing?

Comment: How about setting `width` and `height` attributes inside the SVG definition, just like it's done in example 3 with stackOverflow SVG logo?

Comment: @Mehdi that solved my problem, but have to modify all my SVG which is a bit tedious

Comment: try setting the width in the img tag then if it's easier, otherwise `width: 100%; height: auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it behave this way? Because SVG isn’t (just) an image. SVG is a document.

When you include an HTML file with an `<iframe>`, you don’t expect the text inside to scale when you change the size of the frame. Same with SVG.

SVG images, in contrast, can be drawn at any pixel size, so they don’t need a clearly defined height or width. And they won’t always have a clearly defined aspect ratio. You’re going to need to explicitly provide this information (and more) if you want the SVG to scale to fit the dimensions you give it (i.e., `min-width`).

Helpful article: [How to Scale SVG | CSS-Tricks - CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)

To perform overflow instead you can simply add a `min-width` like so:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  min-width: 640px;
}
```

```html
<!-- resized -->
<img src="https://keyller.io/generators/fr/solfege/cle-de-sol/img/treble-clef-9-sol.svg">

<!-- overflow -->
<!-- <img src="https://www.silicon.fr/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/stack_overflow.jpg"> -->
```

**Edit:**

The SO svg has a `width` and `height` declared while the other does not. The SO svg will try to maintain this `width` which is causing the `overflow` you see. You'll notice if there is a `width` declared on the music svg then it causes overflow as desired.

Width undefined:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://keyller.io/generators/fr/solfege/cle-de-sol/img/treble-clef-9-sol.svg">
```

Width defined: `svg[Attributes Style] {width: 800.12;}`

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg">
```

Solved in chat with a static width and `vmin` `max-height` and `max-width` as well as `object-fit: cover;`

Comment: Thx, but the size of the image is scale with CSS animations, so I can't add the property min-width. I updated the question with a new disturbing example. Can you have a look?

Comment: @Fifi Can I ask why you are using `svg` as an `img` instead of `<svg></svg>`?

Comment: Because image are loaded dynamically. Images can be jpg, svg, png ...

Comment: @Fifi I am aware they can be `img`, just wanted to know if there was a specific reason. Per the article, this could be easily done with the `viewBox` attribute and it's sidekick `preserveAspectRatio`. However, I'll update for using `<img>`.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer. I simplified my example for the question, but unfortunately, there is a CSS `width: auto` on each image that overwrite the inline `width="640"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253029/discussion-between-kameron-and-fifi).